# Bootstrap offset not working in react app, when used with a button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-4

In this snippet I would like to see the button after two col space, but the button is pulled to left and whatever I do, it's not getting updated.

```
{ values.contact_persons_attributes.length < 2 &&
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
      <button className="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({id: '', name: '', email: '', mobile_no: '', is_representative: false})}><span className="btn-label"><i className="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Add Contact Person</button>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: It's no working because `col-md-offset-2` is `offset-md-2` in Bootstrap 4.[Read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Inspect the button and open the computed style. Look for position, display, margin, padding. left, right attributes. See if something is out of place and paste the relevant info to your question.

Comment: @ZimSystem i have tried with that too, it was not working.

Comment: @MotiKorets i have found an alternative luckily, `className="col-md-11  ml-md-auto"`. This did work for me and gave me the desired output.

Comment: I think you should add it as an answer so question appears as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found an alternative luckily, `className="col-md-11 ml-md-auto"`. This did work for me and gave me the desired output.